# How to sign and verify multiple signature pdf file using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, signature

I'm trying to make a simple demo sign and verify multiple signature with pdf file using iText. Signing process was ok, two signature fields showed up when I viewed pdf file using Foxit Reader. But the first signature, foxit announced that it had been altered. I tried to verify again with java code using iText but got the same result. Here is my code:

**Signing**

```
    PdfReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new PdfReader(inputData);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        LOG.error("IOException: " + e1.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfStamper stamper = null;
    try {
        stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, outStream, '\0');
    } catch (DocumentException e1) {
        LOG.error("DocumentException: " + e1.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        LOG.error("IOException: " + e1.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(rect, 1, gen.nextString());
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String singingTime = df.format(new Date());
    String signature = "Signed by: " + author + "\nReason: " + appearance.getReason()  + "\nDate: " + singingTime;
    appearance.setLayer2Text(signature);
    TSAClient tsaCli = null;
    if (useTsa) {
        tsaCli = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl, tsaAccount, tsaPwd);
    }

    try {
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, certChain, null,
                null, tsaCli, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

        result = outStream.toByteArray();

        outStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        LOG.error("DocumentException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        LOG.error("GeneralSecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

**Verifying**

```
 private int verify(byte[] signedData) {
    PdfReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new PdfReader(signedData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("CANNOT LOAD SIGNED DATA. " + e.getMessage());

        return ValidationError.CANNOT_LOAD_SIGNED_DATA;
    }

    AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
    ArrayList<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();

    if (names == null || names.isEmpty()) {
        LOG.error("SIGNATURE NOT FOUND");

        return ValidationError.SIGNATURE_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    for (String name : names) {
        PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(name);

        boolean signatureValid = false;
        try {
            signatureValid = pkcs7.verify();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            LOG.error("Signature with field name " + name + " is invalid");
        }

        if (!signatureValid) {

            LOG.error("[CONTENT]: Document has modified.");
            return ValidationError.SIGNATURE_INVALID; //The first signature return false here.
        }
    }

    return ValidationError.SIGNATURE_VALID;
}
```

And I using iText ver 5.5.8.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702898/itext-pdfstamper-increase-size-of-a-signed-pdf If you don't add the second signature in append mode, it is only normal that you break the first signature!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Hi, when I read createSignature function in append mode, this function require a tempFile. If I don't need it, Can I set it is null? I just need to return result as a byte array.

Comment: Yes, you can set the parameter to create a temporary file to `null`. In that case, everything will happen in memory.

Comment: The code working fine, thank you so much.

Comment: OK, if you create an answer for your question, I can up-vote it, so that other people facing the same problem can be helped by your answer too.

Comment: Thế Hải Nguyễn, @Bruno, either of you should make this an answer. Or we should close this question as duplicate.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39702898/766786